# hide model variable's / property's value from the developer on mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-deployment

I have developed an MVC web application using MVC -5 and visual studio 2017.

I am using the forms authentication hence making the user enter the username and password.

I have a view "Login" where I have my text boxes for username and password and I get the value on the controller using the model called "LoginData.cs"

in my action method, I get the value of password entered by the user in a free text and I don't want the developer to look or have access to this free text for security reasons.

I can not encrypt or do hashing on this free text as 
1. I am not saving the password anywhere in the database 
2. the active directory needs the free text of password to ValidateCredentials

I just don't want the developers in the team to be able to look at the password-free text when they hover their mouse in debugging mode or be able to save these passwords elsewhere by writing some code.

just wondering if there is any way to do this

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginData LoginDataModel)

```
    {


        bool isValid = false;
        using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ""))
        {
            // validate the credentials
             isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(LoginDataModel.Username, LoginDataModel.Password);
        }
```

I just don't want the developers in the team to be able to look at the password-free text when they hover their mouse in debugging mode or be able to save these passwords elsewhere by writing some code.

Comment: If the password is plain text then you cannot stop another developer adding a line of code to save it.

Comment: Perhaps adding a decorator or attribute to the controller and restricting access to that code. A decorator could even be transparent to a non inquisitive developer.

Comment: are developers doing remote debugging of the live environment or something? Because otherwise surely the only password they would see is their own

Comment: But also...why don't you just use integrated windows authentication directly, instead of asking the user to type their Windows username and password? What's the reason for that?

Comment: the password is already masked by using  @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Password but when it comes to the controller it is just a regular string . 

debugging is not done in the live environment but there are many developers in the team, someone can go and write some code which can save all the username and passwords to text file(for example) 

due to our business needs, we can not use windows authentication

Comment: Well the way you stop developers writing code to do that and injecting it into your application is to have proper source control procedures, proper code review procedures, high quality testing and rigorous change management, so that this kind of code could never get anywhere near a production environment.

Comment: But @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Password is very worrying. Are you saying you put the user's current password into a hidden field in the browser? That is not secure at all. Anyone could just open the browser tools and view it. I don't understand what you would want to do that for.

Comment: sorry we have used 
@Html.PasswordFor(a => a.Password)

Comment: Ok that makes more sense. But the point I made about your procedures is the important thing